# Does anyone know if you can use Amazon's s3 on a site developed on the Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-s3

Would one be violating the the terms of agreement with Google App Engine if one were to use Amazon's S3 service with Google App Engine? I do know there is restrictions on what you can and can't do but I was not sure of this.

Having these two combined features, one could provide one heck of a system at a relatively low cost compared to hosting this with a hosting company.

Has anyone done this already or have heard of an application that combines the two technologies?

Comment: Use it to store files, images, attachments etc. It's a storage engine web service.  Instead of storing it on Google App Engine where they only give 500 Megs of disk space.

Comment: Actually, I'm working on a Google App Engine application that allows you to view, add, and delete S3 files.

Comment: Absolutely YES!You also need to take a look at **Google Storage** and **App Engine BlobStore**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer - This should not be construed as legal advice**

I don't know much about the inner workings of your application, but it seems that there is nothing limiting this in Google's or Amazon's Terms of Service. Read through the terms regarding the specifics and if you have further questions, just ask!

Here are Google's current limitations (Prohibited Actions, Content)

- [App Engine Program Policies](http://code.google.com/appengine/program_policies.html)

Here are Amazon's terms of service for S3

- [Amazon's S3 Terms of Service](http://aws.amazon.com/agreement/)

And finally, the terms of service for Google's App Engine

- [App Engine Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/appengine/terms.html)

**Edit:**
Looks like there have been a few people trying this as well. See [here](http://rel.me/2008/09/23/shrub-s3-proxy-service-on-google-app-engine/) and [here](http://www.idlewords.com/2008/08/using_google_app_engine_with_amazon_web_services.htm).

Comment: Thanks!  Good to see others are using the technology together!

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for some file storage for my AppEngine application and found example code that joins AppEngine with S3 (storage and retrieval). Did not try if this works yet, though.

http://opensocial-resources.googlecode.com/svn/samples/cloud/appengine+s3/cloud.py

Answer (score 1):

I am currently developing a GAE app that uses Amazon S3.  Works very well!  The python S3 library works out of the box.

http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=134